# JSP retrieve data from API

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I am new in jsp, and I have a spring boot API on server, how can I retrieve data from api to jsp?
the link is something like: http://111.111.1.111:8080/user/getallusers
this is what i get from postman:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7csL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just treat it the same as **any HTTP network request** you make using java. You can use Java's built in HTTP client library.

Here is an example. (For JSP you can always enclose the code in scriptlet tags <% %> but I would recommend making the call using **servlet** and then sending the response to jsp)

```
URL url = new URL("http://111.111.1.111:8080/user/getallusers ");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + conn.getResponseCode());
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    (conn.getInputStream())));

String output;
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

For more insight you can refer to this link https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Java script to invoke API:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'http://111.111.1.111:8080/user/getallusers', true);
request.onload = function () {

 var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(user => {
      console.log(user.name_en);// Alternatively manipulate DOM with record
    });
  } else {
    console.log('error occurred. Please try again');
  }
}

request.send();
```